# Display all the links from a webpage

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Here is views.py. I want to display all the links contained by 'www.pythonforbeginners.com' but the problem is it only displays the last link of the page. How can I solve it?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def home(request):
    url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.pythonforbeginners.com")
    readurl = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(readurl)
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    for lin in links:
         result = lin.get('href')

    return render(request, 'search/homepage.html', {'result': result, 'url':url})
```

And here is homepage.html

```
{{ result }}
```

[And output I got:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAo7y.png)

Comment: you are doing an iteration, so the last element (privacy-policy) of `links` collection  is assigned to `result` variable. better pass that collection, or its sanitized form to your template file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
def test(request):
    url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.pythonforbeginners.com")
    readurl = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(readurl)
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    result = []
    for lin in links:
        result.append(lin.get('href'))

    return render(request, 'portal_test.html', {'result': result, 'url': url})
```

What you are doing is overriding the result data. You have to use a list and get all data in it. Then in templates use,

```
{% for x in result %}
{{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

Use correct variable names... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your result contains only the last link.Append it to a list in the loop and then send the list to the template.

Right now your result has only last link.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def home(request):
    url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.pythonforbeginners.com")
    readurl = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(readurl)
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    list1 = []
    for lin in links:
        result = lin.get('href')
        list1.append(result)

    return render(request, 'search/homepage.html', {'result': list1,'url':url})
```

This will work..
Your list(list1) will look something like this.
['www.google.com','www.new.com','....','....']

In the  template you can loop over result variable to print each link.(.html file)

```
{% for x in result %}
{{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```